# Can we call a specific svg logo code from a bunch of other svgs logo code all in a jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to use svgs logo but donot want to create a component for every svg logo. I want to store all the svg code I need in a jsx file and want to call it by using either id or className inside a div.

I have tried giving className to my svg code and using it inside a div and it does not show anything.